# How to know actual url in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url

I got into this error:

```
404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.
```

But I want to know where am I? So I can fix the URL.

If it possible how to print the actual URL out.

Update: What is the controller and function.

Comment: Read your question again and update it. If you're in 404 page, then the entered url doesn't exist. Then how can we Identify the actual url ?

Comment: I mean the controller and function.

Comment: You've entered a wrong url so either the controller name or the function name will be wrong.

Comment: First thing in codeigniter is to review your application/config.php, htaccess in website root, check if controller starts with Uppercase (the filename) and has index function. And for checking where you script executes I would put `echo dirname(__FILE__);` inside index.php .

Comment: Even it wrong can we print the name of the controller and function out?

Comment: It won't show you current controller, you will just know, where the script lies in server directory. Better check if any url works, like: yourdomain.com/welcome or your domain.com/index.php/welcome (these both should point to index function inside welcome controller)

Comment: what is your address bar url @NamHao

Comment: You could try `$this->uri->uri_string()` this will return the current URI without the base URL. I'm not sure if this changes when to the name of the 404 controller/method, it might be worth a try. You might have to set a 404 override controller/method in your routes.php config file.

Answer (score 0):

to debug such errors, you can do this

in application/config/routes.php at the end of the file add

```
$route[(:any+)]   = 'process/processing/$1/$2/$3/$4';
```

create a file in application/controller/process.php

```
function processing($controller, $method, $param1, $param2){
    echo "$controller <br> $method <br> $param2 <br> $param2";
}
```

Hope this helpyou